# How do I get my settings to update in my app without having to run the script again?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

So I'm trying to make a password generator in PySimpleGUI, but settings won't update until I run the script again (although they do update in the .ini file)

I think the problem lies somewhere within these blocks
This is just part of the program obviously I removed a bunch of stuff that I figured were unimportant

```py
def generate_password():
    password = ""
    password_char = settings["PASS"]["chars"]
    for i in range(password_length):
        password += "".join(secrets.choice(password_char))
        
    settings["PASS"]["password"] = password
    text_file = open(USERNAME, "a")
    text_file.write(password)
    text_file.close()

    while True:
        for i in range(password_length):
            password += "".join(secrets.choice(password_char))
        break
    settings["PASS"]["password"] = password
    print(password)
    print(password_char)

def main_window():
    #--Create the menu at the top of the app
    menu_def = [
        ["Toolbar", ["Command 1", "Command 2"]],
                ["Help", ["Settings", "About"]]
    ]
    #--Create the two main layouts
    layoutUpdate = [
        [sg.Text("User: " + USERNAME, key="xxx"), sg.Text(size=(15,1))],
        [sg.Text("---")], 
        [sg.Text("Welcome to my password generator!")],
        [sg.Text("Your current settings: "), sg.Text("Characters included: " + password_char, key="char"), sg.Text("Length of password: " + password_len_disp, key="len")],
        [sg.Sizer(v_pixels=355)],
        [sg.Button("Generate Password"), sg.Button("Settings")],
        ]
    layout_final = [
        [sg.Text("Here is your password, " + USERNAME, key="yyy")],
        [sg.Text(password, key="pass")],
        [sg.Sizer(v_pixels=400)],
        [sg.Button("Reload App")],
    ]
    #--Make it possible to switch between the two main layouts
    layout = [
        [sg.MenubarCustom(menu_def, tearoff=False)],
        [sg.Column(layoutUpdate, key="-COL1-"),
         sg.Column(layout_final, key="-COL2-", visible=False)],
        [sg.Button("Exit")],
    ]
    #--Get window title from ini file and create the main window
    window_title = settings["GUI"]["title"]
    window = sg.Window(window_title, layout, location=(0,0), size=(800,600), keep_on_top=True, finalize=True)

 if event == "Generate Password":
            generate_password()
            window[f"-COL{layout}-"].update(visible=False)
            if layout < 2:
                layout += 1
                NAME=settings["USER"]["person_1"]
                pw=settings["PASS"]["password"]
                window["yyy"].update(NAME)
                window["pass"].update(pw)
                window[f"-COL{layout}-"].update(visible=True)
        if event == "Reload App":
            window[f"-COL{layout}-"].update(visible=False)
            window["-COL1-"].update(visible=True)
            layout = 1
        elif event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Exit"):
            break
        #--Open settings window
        if event == "Settings":
            window.disappear()
            settings_window(settings)
            number="Length of password: "+str(settings["PASS"]["length"])
            NAME=settings["USER"]["person_1"]
            char="Characters included: "+settings["PASS"]["chars"]
            window["len"].update(number)
            window["xxx"].update(NAME)
            window["char"].update(char)
            window.reappear()
    window.close()



if __name__ == "__main__": 
    SETTINGS_PATH = str(Path.cwd())
    
#--Locate ini file
    settings = sg.UserSettings(
    path=SETTINGS_PATH, filename="pp.ini", use_config_file=True, convert_bools_and_none=True
    )
#--Assign variables from ini file
    theme = settings["GUI"]["theme"]
    font_family = settings["GUI"]["font_family"]
    font_size = int(settings["GUI"]["font_size"])
    USERNAME = settings["USER"]["person_1"]
    password_length = int(settings["PASS"]["length"])
    password_char = settings["PASS"]["char"]
    password = ""
    password = settings["PASS"]["password"]

    main_window()
```

So I was tired when I posted this and forgot to mention I have tried both

window.read( ) // window.refresh( )

in multiple places

Comment: So basically if I run the script it will work fine and generate a password, however if I change settings via the settings window it won't update in the app (it only updates in the ini file). My question is how can I make it to where I don't need to rerun the script for my settings to be applied in the app?

Comment: "it won't update in the app", won't update what ? If it is for the GUI, basically, you need to call `window.read()` to update the GUI and handle all the events in your GUI, or call `window.refresh()` to update the GUI immediately.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really bad at asking questions. I have edited my above script to include more which may make it more obvious what I'm talking about. When I run the script and  change the settings it writes those settings to the .ini file instantly, but yes I cannot get the GUI to display these changes until I close and relaunch the script. I bet the answer is as simple as you say, but I've tried doing that in a couple different places and it hasn't seemed to work. I really appreciate all of your input!

Comment: It looks like that you didn't update the values to elements on the GUI, only switch between the layouts. Try to add key to element, and update it like `window[key].update(new_value)'.

Comment: @JasonYang Thank you so much I have finally fixed my script!! Now there are only a few more bugs to fix and some cosmetic issues to tackle before I'm happy with it. It would have taken me forever to figure this out on my own, so I am truly grateful!!